# Uncaught Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: Socket constructor in dart with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dart, database-connection

I am trying to connect dart with database(optional like postgrelsql,mongodb). I installed postgresql and created db,table and goto pubspec.yaml then add depencies postgresql and run pub get.
    then i mentioned the library file

```
import 'package:postgresql/postgresql.dart';
```

connection details

```
  var uri = 'postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/testdb';
   connect(uri).then((conn) {  
   });
```

but I got following error which I cant understand clearly. pls help me.

```
Stack Trace:

Uncaught Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: Socket constructor
```

Stack Trace:
Unsupported operation: Socket constructor
    at dart.wrapException (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:2531:15)
    at null.Socket_connect (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:11612:13)
    at dart.Socket_connect [as call$2] (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:11614:14)
    at ConnectionImpl_connect_closure.dart.ConnectionImpl_connect_closure.call$0 (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:13515:28)
    at dart.Future_Future$sync (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:4723:28)
    at dart.ConnectionImpl.static.ConnectionImpl_connect (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:13468:18)
    at dart.connect (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:12861:14)
    at dart.PostgrelSqlconn (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:12836:7)
    at main (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:12825:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.dart._wrapJsFunctionForAsync [as _captured_protected_1] (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:2923:11) (http://localhost:8080/dbconnection.dart.js:2531)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run this code in the browser. Postgresql doesn't work from the browser. Mongodb does have an HTTP API Which allows to access it directly from code running in the browser. 
Usually database access is handled by a service running on a server and the browser sends commands to this service to store and retrieve data and the service forwards the request to the database. Alternatively you can use ready-to-use severs like Firebase.

Comment: where can I write server codes? Is it any other clear doc for connecting database to dart.

Comment: Create a `main.dart` file (just an example name) in the `bin` subdirectory of a Dart package with a `main() {}`. I don't know about general documentation for database access from Dart. The examples from the used database packages (like sqljocky) are probably the closest to documentation and the documentation of the used database.